# What is the significance of a router advertisement prefix with L and A bits set to 0?

Tags: ipv6

[RFC 4861, section 4.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861#section-4.6.2) describes the prefix option for router advertisement packets. There are two flags that are part of that option `L` and `A` which indicate the prefix is usable on-link and for [SLAAC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862) respectively. What is the practical implication of both of those bits being set to zero?

Possibilities I have considered:

- in a multiple router configuration, such an option would indicate prefixes reachable via that particular router via a shorter route than the default route
- if the router advertisement is unicast to a host acting as router downstream, it could serve as a simple implementation of prefix delegation